# RadioButton returns false after first run

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone and happy new year.

I have a problem. After the time a radiobutton.isChecked() is true returns always false. For example,

```
if (rb.isChecked()) //do something
```

This if statement executed only once. How can I fix it? I also tried the isSelected() but it didn't work.

Every help appreciated! :)

Comment: Is the `RadioButton` placed in a `RadioGroup`?

Comment: You want to execute the code below your if statement each time the radio button was selected, or what?

Comment: you should add the code both java and xml side

Comment: Yes it belongs to `RadioGroup`. Also, here it's the code `if(tichuMadeA.isChecked())

                    tempA += 100;` and the xml `<RadioGroup

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/teamARadioGroup">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tichuMadeA"
                android:text="Tichu Made"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I bypassed it in this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
private boolean check=false;
...
...
...
public void checked(View arg0)
{
     if(!check)
     check=true;
     else
     check=false;
}
...
...
...
}
```

Then in the layout in the RadioButton you have to set

```
android:onClick="checked"
```

In this way you'll always know if the radiobutton is cheked or not. 
I simply exploited an instance variable to control condition of the radiobutton.

Comment: I will try that later and I will answer you if it'll work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Panos Gr If it doesn't work, tell me what's the problem, so we can solve it ;)

Comment: @Panos Gr oh sorry! I forgot to put the parameters in checked method! Look at the answer, I updated it

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you very much.