# Cannot invoke isSelected(); on a primitive type boolean

Tags: java, eclipse

the error is on line "grill = (String)
grilled.isSelected();" and grilled is a previously proclaimed JCheckBox: Grilled?, and I keep getting the error "Cannot invoke isSelected(); on a primitive type boolean"

I just want to get the grilled checkbox, so that when checked on my applet, will return the string

```
public void displayData()
 { 
     System.out.println(" At Method Display Data");
     String ssize, sandwich, drink, side, grill;
     ssize = (String) size.getSelectedItem();
     boolean  grilled = true;
        String str = String.valueOf(grilled);
        System.out.println("String is: "+str);
     grill = (String) grilled.isSelected();
     sandwich = (String) Sandwiches.getSelectedValue();
     side = (String) Drinks.getSelectedValue();
     drink = (String) Sides.getSelectedValue();

    JTextField textDisplay = new JTextField (ssize+ grill 
               + sandwich + side + "with" + drink);
```

}

Comment: So `grilled` is equal to `true`. What is `grilled.isSelected()` supposed to do?

Comment: I never use the method isSelected(). I advise you to use a boolean instance variable: `boolean checked=false` and then change it using onClick: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446484/radiobutton-returns-false-after-first-run/41447094#41447094

Comment: I read that it was supposed to return if the checkbox was checked or not, this is my first interactive applet, and I want the string "grilled" to be displayed on a JFrame when the user checks it and after they've placed their order- this is a part of a larger sandwich shop applet that I'm doing for class and its 350 lines long and I didn't want to post the entire thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In posted code

```
 boolean  grilled = true;
 // ...
 grill = (String) grilled.isSelected();
```

I suppose you want to get this field instead of that local variable

```
public class ... {
    JCheckBox grilled;
    //...
}
```

This is called *[shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)*. When looking up what that name refers to, the local variable has greater priority than a field, so compiler thinks you are refering to the local variable instead, contradicting your true intention.

You should use `this.grilled` to refer to the field. Replace `grill = (String) grilled.isSelected();` with `grill = String.valueOf(this.grilled.isSelected());`, assuming your field and your method lives in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming isSelected returns boolean value and you are trying to take it as String. You can do like this

```
String tmp = "" + isSelected()
```